# Converting cURL to jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an API call with jQuery AJAX using curl as given to me by the backend team.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://example1.com/api/sms \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 's: APP' \
  -d '{ 
   "mobile": "1110002222"
 }'
```

But it is throwing a 403 forbidden error:

```
Invalid CORS request
```

This is the code hosted on another domain name (example2.com):

```js
data = {mobile: '0001112222' };
success = function(data) { console.log(data); };
headers = {s: 'APP'};
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'https://example1.com/api/sms',
 data: data,
 success: success,
 dataType: 'json',
 headers: headers
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: `Invalid CORS request` - that's what you need to research ... CORS ... just because `curl` can do something, does not mean a browser can ... a browser can only make a cross origin request to a server that allows a cross origin request

Comment: Have you tried to complete the headers with headers ={ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 's': 'APP'} ?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette Same error but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question, try this code instead:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "url": "https://example1.com/api/sms",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "s": "APP",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\"mobile\": \"1110002222\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

for this request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://example1.com/api/sms \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 's: APP' \
  -d '{"mobile": "1110002222"}'
```

Comment: CORS issues aside, this is a good thing to point out. I do think `JSON.stringify()` would be better though and jQuery also has a specific `contentType` option for `$.ajax()`. `crossDomain` is also useless here

Comment: Yeah I know that jQuery has the content-type option but I want to exactly map the cURL request to jQuery AJAX. I agree with you that crossDomain option is useless so I removed it.

Comment: Same error. But thank You.